# Error trying to compile latex document. Where can I find the file "report output*"?

Tags: emacs, latex, compilation, auctex

Help!!!

I am trying to compile a LaTeX document that has been compiled before, but now for some reason it just won't go through. The error message I am getting is not very informative, and I can't even find the file it is pointing to.

The details: I am using Aquamacs, and when I try to compile the document the mini-buffer displays the following message:

[image]

When I press C-c ` this is what I get:

> --- TeX said --- \Hy@AtBeginDocument ->\ltx@LocalAppendToMacro
>                                                 \Hy@AtBeginDocumentHook  l.735
>   ...r\Hy@AtBeginDocument\expandafter{\Hy@temp
>                                                     }
>   --- HELP --- TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably
>   misspelled the name. If this message
>   occurs when a LaTeX command is being
>   processed, the command is probably in
>   the wrong place---for example, the
>   error can be produced by an \item
>   command that's not inside a
>   list-making environment. The error can
>   also be caused by a missing
>   \documentclass command.

The problem is, I can't even find this file referred to in the mini-buffer (report output*) - believe me, it is not in the directory they say it is. My LaTeX document has only 191 lines, and the error supposedly is on line 735.

I have checked the whole document looking for something that could be wrong, but I haven't been able to find anything.

It might not have anything to do with this, but earlier today I was rearranging my whole .emacs file and I might have done something which interferes with auctex or latex, but I tried compiling another file and it worked.

Thanks  :)

Comment: looking at your image, the reason why you were not able to find your report output file might be that it was a new buffer created by emacs, not a new file. The * at both ends of the buffer name indicates that it isn't an actual file. You would have been able to see the buffer in the emacs buffer list (C-x C-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a clean compile of the document *outside* of emacs (i.e., just run the latex command from a terminal) and see what happens.  The log file will be in the current directory. Also, it will run latex in interactive mode, so you'll have a better idea of what went wrong.

Comment: I am very embarrassed to say I don't know how to compile from the terminal (even though the first time I compiled a latex document was from the command window in Windows). I used TextMate instead, and it seems that the problem was with the package hyperref. For some reason once I deleted the call to this package everything worked again. I will check why that is so, but in any case, thanks for your help  :)

Comment: It is though disappointing that I have to use another software to do that. I should be able to do all of that in Emacs...

Comment: you don't need another software...
do: M-x eshell RET

this will bring up a shell, then enter: pdflatex filename.tex